# Adding .NET App to Registry to Launch after Reboot to Complete Certain Actions

Tags: c#, .net, windows, reboot

If my app needs to reboot the system to change something and I'd like it to automatically continue its actions after the reboot, how can I add a key to the registry (more importantly, where in the registry) to launch the app on the first reboot? Just to be clear, I want this reboot-launch to happen only once. In other words, once the computer reboots, the app is launched, and on the next bootup/reboot, it isn't launched automatically.

Should this be done by just adding a "launch at startup" key and then removing it? I have a feeling that there's a dedicated registry area for reboot actions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, there is.  The [RunOnce key.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Looks good. Could you point me to some sample code that shows how to add an app to it? Thx.